# Выборка запросов CREATE TABLE с файла .sql без комментариев

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярного выражения выбрать все запросы с файла, которые не закомментированы?
Вот пример, который у меня получился: https://regex101.com/r/mR9fD4/19

Только он не вытягивает первый CREATE, так как никакой символ перед ним не идет. Как это исправить?

Comment: `(^|[^- ])CREATE TABLE [^;]*;`. Хотя `(?sm)(^|[^- ])CREATE TABLE .*?;$` лучше, вдруг какие-нибудь `;` есть в тексте.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, работает, спасибо)

Comment: А о существовании `/* блочных комментариев */` Вы не забыли?

Comment: @Akina, тогда вот так: (?sm)(^|[^- #\/*])CREATE TABLE .*?;$ , если уже брать и комментарии с #

Comment: С диезом всё совсем просто - попался не в литерале, до конца строки комментарий. С двумя тире хуже - после них нужен пробел, иначе это ни разу не комментарий. Совсем плохо дело с блоками - они могут быть вложенными и пересекающимися... или начальный абы бордюр блока может быть в комментарии под диезом или двумя минусами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут необходимо чередование с `^`: `(^|[^- ])`.

Рекомендую

```
(?sm)(^|[^- ])CREATE TABLE .*?;$
```

См. [демо](https://regex101.com/r/6cOCrn/1)

- `(?sm)` - модификаторы, позволяющие точке находить символы перехода на новую строку и символам `^` и `$`  находить позиции начала/конца каждой строки в тексте
- `(^|[^- ])` - начало строки или любой символ, отличный от `-` и пробела
- `CREATE TABLE`  - текст `CREATE TABLE`
- `.*?;` - 0 и более символов, как можно меньше и `;`
- `$` - конец строки.